# How to get similar arrays in two lists using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists characterized as such:

```
circles_1 = [
        array([[
        [342.      , 198.      ,  28.600698],
        [ 58.      , 166.      ,  28.600698],
        [282.      ,  82.      ,  28.600698]]], dtype=float32), 
        array([[
        [ 78.      , 174.      ,  24.351591],
        [302.      , 234.      ,  24.207438],
        [314.      , 114.      ,  23.43075 ]]], dtype=float32)]

 circles_2 = [
    array([[
    [ 76.5     , 193.5     ,  21.505814],
    [355.5     , 121.5     ,  22.726637],
    [355.5     , 274.5     ,  22.726637]]], dtype=float32), 
    array([[
    [ 76.5     , 193.5     ,  21.505814],
    [355.5     , 121.5     ,  22.726637],
    [355.5     , 274.5     ,  22.726637]]], dtype=float32)]
```

If there exist possible array duplicates between the two lists, how can I get them using numpy? Is there a better way than looping through circles_1 and then for each element checking if it exists in circles_2?

Comment: Can you define "duplicates between the two lists"? Do you mean that the entire array of 9 elements must match exactly between `circles_1` and `circles_2`?

Comment: Well, in this case each circle is a triple pair. I want to find any duplicate circles that exist in circle_1 and circle_2. So for example, I want to see if `[342.      , 198.      ,  28.600698]` from `circle_1` exists anywhere in `circle_2`. And repeat that for every element in circles_1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one brute-force way:

```
from numpy import array, float32, vstack, array_equal

circles_1 = [
        array([[
        [342.      , 198.      ,  28.600698],
        [ 58.      , 166.      ,  28.600698],
        [282.      ,  82.      ,  28.600698]]], dtype=float32), 
        array([[
        [ 78.      , 174.      ,  24.351591],
        [302.      , 234.      ,  24.207438],
        [314.      , 114.      ,  23.43075 ]]], dtype=float32)]

circles_2 = [
        array([[
        [ 76.5     , 193.5     ,  21.505814],
        [58        , 166       ,  28.600698],
        [355.5     , 274.5     ,  22.726637]]], dtype=float32), 
        array([[
        [ 76.5     , 193.5     ,  21.505814],
        [355.5     , 121.5     ,  22.726637],
        [355.5     , 274.5     ,  22.726637]]], dtype=float32)]

def check_duplicates(c1, c2):
    c1_concat = vstack(c1).flatten().reshape((6,3))
    c2_concat = vstack(c2).flatten().reshape((6,3))

    for i in range(c1_concat.shape[0]):
        x = c1_concat[i]
        for j in range(c2_concat.shape[0]):
            y = c2_concat[j]
            if array_equal(x, y):
                yield x

list(check_duplicates(circles_1, circles_2))

# [array([  58.        ,  166.        ,   28.60069847], dtype=float32)]
```